# A question on the Diagonal Theorem of Functional Analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Could you please help me understand why from the stated conditions it follows that each row in the matrix $x_{q_i q_j}$ converges to zero, as the proof of the theorem claims?

[image]

This is given for the columns but it's apparently a lot more subtle for the rows. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that since the sum in (b) must eventually be finite (for sufficiently large $i$) then the sum has a tail which vanishes.  Without loss of generality we can pass to a subsequence so that the sum is finite for all $i$. Then, convergence of the sum implies $x_{q_i q_j}\to 0$ as $j\to \infty$.

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt, thanks for your comment. If you would like to write it with more detail as an answer, I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lim_{i\to \infty} \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_{q_i q_j} = 0$ then the sum is eventually finite. Thus we may pass to an additional subsequence $(q_i)$ (abusing notation) so that $\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_{q_i q_j} <\infty$ for all $i$. An infinite sum is finite only if the terms converge to zero, so $x_{q_i q_j} \to 0$ as $j\to \infty$ for each $i$. On the other hand (a) implies that $x_{q_i q_j} \to 0$ as $i\to \infty$ for each $j$. Thus each matrix row and column converges to zero as claimed.

Comment: But what about the sum of terms such as $-1, 1, -1, 1, \ldots$. Isn't that a finite sum?

Comment: No this is not finite.  A sum $\sum x_i$ is finite only if its partial sums $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ converge: $S_n \to S$. In the alternating sequence you give you have $S_1 = -1$, $S_2 = 0$, $S_3 = -1$, and so on. This does not converge and so the sum is not finite.

Comment: Aha, thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck!